# Vertex AI - Deployed Model Prediction is Different From Prediction in Evaluation Results

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have trained a multi-label text classification model using AutoML. I then deployed the model and attempted testing some of the inputs that we presented in the evaluation tab of the model registry.  The problem I am having is that the predicted output values that I obtained via both testing methods does not match the output values which were presented in the evaluation tab of the model registry (I have included pictures of one such exapmle).
[Model prediction in evaluate tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQBoj.png)
[Model prediction in deploy/test tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC89x.png)

I have checked that the correct model (and version of the model. There is only one version of this model) was deployed and I have tried undeploying and redeploying the model. I have checked that the input I am using is that same by copying and pasting the input from the evaluation page to the deploy/test page. I tried using the "Test Your Model" preview feature as well as the python code as presented in the "sample request" on the testing page. I have checked that the predictions from both testing methods (Deploy/Test page and the python API request) match each other so I'm pretty certain it has something to do with the way I am deploying. I used the "Deploy To Endpoint" button on the Deploy/Test page to deploy the model. Within that workflow, I only entered the endpoint name and left all of the other parameters set as the default including sending 100% of the traffic to the this model.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

It’s not a bug; it’s a feature! There are actually two models: one for evaluation and one for serving. The evaluation model is trained using the training and validation sets. The serving model is derived from the evaluation model by further training on the entire data set, including the test set, because it is assumed that a user would want to make new predictions based on as much past data as possible.

I requested that the Vertex AI team add documentation for this special behavior. I also requested the ability to use/export the evaluation model in addition to the serving model.

---

## Original Answer

I am also encountering the same issue, although it is for a tabular classification model. I reported the bug to the Vertex AI team.

I suggest you to use the “Send feedback” button on the evaluation page to [file a bug](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/support/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests). Include as much information as you can and also mention that it may be a duplicate of “b/298236642”. Hopefully, more bug reports for the same issue will help the team prioritize resolving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to deploy the model using the gcloud command-line tool instead of using the "Deploy To Endpoint" button on the Deploy/Test page. Here's an example command:

```
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-endpoint my-endpoint \ --region=us-central1 \ --model=my-model \ --traffic-split=0=1 \ --min-replica-count=1 \ --max-replica-count=1
```

Try also checking the logs for your deployed model to see if there are any errors or warnings that might help you diagnose the issue. You can view logs using the following command:

```
gcloud ai logs read my-endpoint
```